# Make table customizable/transportable?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I've got a table which was set up wrong ( as an application table, but a maintanence view was created ) but it should be an customizing table, so that we are able to transport the entries of the table.

So far I changed the type and maintainablity of the table, now it is type C ( Customizing ) and changes can be made without restrictions. I've also changed in the technical settings the type to APPL2, so it is a customizing-table. After those changes I've deleted the original table maintanence generator view and generated a new one.

My problem is, that when I save my new / changed entries in sm30, I won't get asked for a transport request and the option to put them into the transport request in sm30 ( via the menue ) is not available. It is outgreyed.

How can I change my table / what do I need to do, that I am able to transport my customizing entries?

Comment: When the table maintenance is created, there are radiobuttons at the bottom of the screen. Make sure the "Standard recording routine" is selected

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai You should post this as an answer. I am 95% sure that this is the answer. Most people don't realize that "recording routine" refers to the transport system and not to change documents.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Table-Maintenance-Generator there is an option called "Standard recording routine" which needs to be selected.

of course credits go to @JózsefSzikszai who gave the answer in the comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Just follow these steps:
More->Utilities->Table Maintenance Generator.
Under Dialog Data Transport Details select "**Standard recording routine**"

[image: Table Maintenance Generator Path]

[image: Recording routine]